# MySQL "ORDER BY" the amount of rows with the same value for a certain column?

Tags: sql, mysql, ranking

I have a table called `trends_points`, this table has the following columns:

- id (the unique id of the row)
- userId (the id of the user that has entered this in the table)
- term (a word)
- time (a unix timestamp)

Now, I'm trying to run a query on this table which will get the rows in a specific time frame ordered by how many times the column `term` appears in the table during the specific timeframe...So for example if the table has the following rows:

```
id | userId | term        | time
------------------------------------
1    28       new year      1262231638
2    37       new year      1262231658
3    1        christmas     1262231666
4    34       new year      1262231665
5    12       christmas     1262231667
6    52       twitter       1262231669
```

I'd like the rows to come out ordered like this:

```
new year
christmas
twitter
```

This is because "new year" exists three times in the timeframe, "christmas" exists twice and "twitter" is only in one row.

So far I've asummed it's a simple WHERE for the specific timeframe part of the query and a GROUP BY to stop the same term from coming up twice in the list.

This makes the following query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `trends_points` 
 WHERE ( time >= <time-period_start> 
  AND time <= <time-period_end> ) 
GROUP BY `term`
```

Does anyone know how I'd do the final part of the query? (Ordering the query's results by how many rows contain the same "term" column value..).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT tp.term,
         COUNT(*) 'term_count'
    FROM TREND_POINTS tp
   WHERE tp.time BETWEEN <time-period_start> AND <time-period_end> 
GROUP BY tp.term
ORDER BY term_count DESC, tp.term
```

See [this question about why to use BETWEEN vs using the >=/<= operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960801/why-to-use-between-operator-while-we-can-do-without-it).

Keep in mind there can be ties - the order by defaults to alphabetically shorting by term value when this happens, but there could be other criteria.

Also, if you want to additionally limit the number of rows/terms coming back you can add the [`LIMIT` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) to the end of the query.  For example, this query will return the top five terms:

```
  SELECT tp.term,
         COUNT(*) 'term_count'
    FROM TREND_POINTS tp
   WHERE tp.time BETWEEN <time-period_start> AND <time-period_end> 
GROUP BY tp.term
ORDER BY term_count DESC, tp.term
   LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer:

```
SELECT 
   term, count(*) as thecount
FROM 
   mytable
WHERE
   (...)
GROUP BY 
   term
ORDER BY 
   thecount DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.term
FROM trend_points t
WHERE t.time >= <time-period_start> AND t.time <= <time-period_end>
ORDER BY COUNT(t.term) DESC
GROUP BY t.term
```

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` will give you the number of rows in the group, so just order by that.

```
SELECT * FROM `trends_points`
WHERE ( `time` >= <time-period_start> AND `time` <= <time-period_end> )
ORDER BY COUNT(`term`) DESC
GROUP BY `term`
```

Comment: Great! Also, consider OMG Ponies' note about BETWEEN.