# How does MySQL implement the `BETWEEN`?

Tags: mysql, sql

Are the range boundries included in MySQL's between? For example if I do

`date between '2013/12/02' AND '2013/12/01'`

will they be included as well? Also which one is better? either I should use `BETWEEN` or should I rely on `<=` and `>=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. **This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments are of the same type**. Otherwise type conversion takes place according to the rules described in Section 12.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”, but applied to all the three arguments.

Comment: Why do you think there's a mistake in the manual? Looks fine to me.

Comment: @MattGibson Because "If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max" is not the same as "MIN less-than-or-equal-to EXPR && MAX less-than-or-equal-to EXPR." **Ah**. Of course you're right. Stop the presses. Didn't realize that it wasn't `min <= expr AND max <= expr`.

Answer (score 0):

Between has better efficiency.  It fixes an issue where MYSQL may have unneeded reevaluations of the conditions.

See this answer: [Why use the BETWEEN operator when we can do without it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960801/why-use-the-between-operator-when-we-can-do-without-it)

Answer (score 0):

If your date values are actually datetime values, and the time component is not always '00:00:00', then neither suggestion in the question is good.   You want a variation of the second one.  Specifically, you want

```
where yourfield >= your start date
and your field < the day after your end date
```