# Difference Between Between and <= & >=

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to take dates between two date intervals.

I Have Tried two queries as below

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BudgetOffice] BUD
            where  Week      BETWEEN '2015-08-03' AND '2015-08-03'.

 SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BudgetOffice] BUD
            where  Week      >= '2015-08-03' AND Week <= '2015-08-03'.
```

Both Returns same results. I thought that

> `between`

will return only the values lies in between the input values and exclude the input values. Is that correct?. If both are same which one more feasible with performance.?

Comment: [between](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) - *BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.* As for performance, you can check the execution plan and you will find that both yield the same execution plan.

Comment: There are some issues around using between operator with date values, Aaron Bertrand has explained it in his article [`What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) definitely worth a read.

Comment: @M.Ali So I guess I overestimated the average programmer's skill around datetime when I assumed that generating reports on a monthly basis would use sth. like `SELECT * FROM data GROUP BY YEAR(datetime),MONTH(datetime)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider snippet:

```
SELECT * FROM list_of_integers_from_1_to_100 AS table
WHERE table.number BETWEEN 2 AND 80;
```

This method is by far more readable than "table.number >= 2 AND table.number <= 80". BETWEEN will return all values which are between 2 and 80 (including both numbers) which is effectively the same.

Performance wise, as far as I know, there is no major differences.

There are couple of nifty things to do with BETWEEN that are simpler than using operators. Consider:

```
table.number NOT BETWEEN 2 AND 80
```

And:

```
table.number < 2 AND table.number > 80
```

Which one is easier on the first glance? I vote for the first one, but in the end it is completely your choice which one to use.

Also, as pointed out in [top answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960801/why-use-the-between-operator-when-we-can-do-without-it;), BETWEEN can help you avoid unnecessary evaluations. I will copy-paste snippet from that topic:

```
SELECT  AVG(RAND(20091225) BETWEEN 0.2 AND 0.4)
FROM    t_source;

---
0.1998

SELECT  AVG(RAND(20091225) >= 0.2 AND RAND(20091225) <= 0.4)
FROM    t_source;

---
0.3199
```